# My basement kitchen has this circuit (20AMPs or 40AMPS-not sure) , can I run power tools on it?

Tags: circuit-breaker

The breakers of my basement kitchen show like below (the 40 ones). The plug is close top my garage where I might need more power. Since that kitchen is not used, can I use a extender power cord to bring power to my garage (under 5m distance) and use power tools on this circuit? I need to run a dust collector rated at 20AMPs peak power. I run it dry just fine on the existing circuit but I am afraid that when I attached to the DC system and when I run the table saw (Ridgid 3650) I might overload the garage circuit

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is a 40A circuit **at 240V**.

It's possible to split a 240V circuit into dual 120V circuits, but then, it's the amperage on the breaker -- i.e. this splits into two 40A circuits, not into two 20A.

So a 40A breaker is absolutely useless for creating 20A circuits.

If you want 20A circuits, the breaker must be 20A.

This 40A breaker is certainly for an electric range.  Another problem you have is that electric ranges of this era were wired without a ground wire.  **Trying to run equipment in a garage without a ground wire would be *nuts***.   It would take a great deal of re-work to try to turn this wiring into a usable circuit that could feed a subpanel, or be down-breakered to directly serve 20A circuits.  The breakers are cheap enough; it's the cost of retrofitting a ground.

However, a kitchen will certainly have ordinary kitchen countertop receptacles. It's supposed to have two 20A circuits. That should be plenty for saw and dust collector.

And you are correct, saw + dust collector on the same circuit is not likely to work.

Comment: thanks for this answer and for the other one, both clear and spot on. I will soon post a new question with more details about my electrical panel. This is an old house 60Y old with wiring redone somewhere mid way...you might get a better idea how recent by looking at the panel
I am not looking for much higher aperage, I just need enough to run my things in the garage (hobbyist, not sure how far this will take me). From what I am reading around 20AMPS should be enough for my needs
the Garage has a GFI /ground wire. Can I run 2 tools on a 20AMP circuit?

Comment: ...That depends on the two tools, and how much power they each use. **If** you need to run them **at the same time** - you can run 10 tools one at a time, no problem....